# ImportError: cannot import name 'ClassVar' after installing airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have followed the steps to install Airflow from below link

[Airflow installation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html) and getting this below error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
  from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  from airflow.models import DAG
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 21, in 
  <module>
  from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator, BaseOperatorLink  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 30, in 
  <module>
  from typing import Any, Callable, ClassVar, Dict, FrozenSet, Iterable, List, Optional, 
  Set, Type, Union
  ImportError: cannot import name 'ClassVar'
```

Can somebody help me here

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday. Quick fix is to install airflow with version 1.10.6

Comment: @P.Panayotov are you able to know what is the reasons for the above error

Comment: as what i can see the problem is with your version of Python. The library typing was not official on Python 3.5, so one fix can be to update your version of Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered the same error as well in my case:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 3.5
- Airflow 1.10.10

After some checking, I found it was a python version issue that the python3.5 doesn't support the module typing.ClassVar: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html

```
As introduced in PEP 526, a variable annotation wrapped in ClassVar indicates that a given attribute is intended to be used as a class variable and should not be set on instances of that class.
```

And checked in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) I found this feature only support from 3.6, oh....

Thus the solution was to upgrade the Python version to 3.6+ to install Airflow 1.10.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.7
sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3.7-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.7-venv
```

After all above, the processes executed successfully.
As a perfection for the official guide, the environment requirement for installation will be:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- **Python 3.6+**
- Airflow 1.10.10